# Parse query returning no results

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

Running a query on Parse db with 600k rows. The object I want is there but it still returns nothing. Everything was working for several weeks and then randomly stopped. Any ideas? Here is the query:

```
// make query on parse database to find code the person entered
                    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "code")
                    query.whereKey("code", containsString: self.codeInput.text!.uppercaseString)
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    // store results
                    let results: NSArray = (array: objects!)

                    // Log the error if there is one
                    if (error != nil) {
                        self.wrongCodeAnimation()
                        print("error " + error!.localizedDescription)
                    }

                        // if there aren't any results, do wrong code animation
                    else if(results.count == 0){
                        print("nothing")
                        print(results)
                        self.wrongCodeAnimation()
                    }

                        // If no error, get array of results and validate the code, get the actual code for that object, and the valid state so we can pass them into the validate function
                    else {
                        let object: PFObject = results.objectAtIndex(0) as! PFObject
                        let code: String = object.objectForKey("code") as! String
                        let codeValid: Bool = object.objectForKey("valid") as! Bool
                        print(codeValid)
                        print(code)
                        self.validateCode(code, codeValid: codeValid, codeObject: object)
                    }

                }
```

Comment: i have no knowledge of swift but you are converting code to uppercase.. did you check it exists  on data browser.. can you try running that query on parse browser directly to verify

Comment: @virendrao It does exist in the data browser, and all of the codes are uppercase. I just convert to uppercase incase the person accidentally added a lowercase character.

Comment: is there any limitation on number of request for parse reached for month ?

Comment: Try to remove your query.whereKey and replace with "query.limit = 10", to be sure that you have datas.

Comment: 30reqs / second, 1 job. Free plan

Comment: @HoaParis tried for a test and I get 10 objects back. It seems to be a problem of querying for a specific object. so 1 / 600,000 in my case.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many rows you can query against in Parse? I know there is a 1000 limit for how many results you can return

Answer (score 0):

So apparently changing

```
query.whereKey("code", containsString: self.codeInput.text!.uppercaseString)
```

to

```
query.whereKey("code", equalTo: self.codeInput.text!.uppercaseString)
```

is doing the trick. Anyone know why this would have any effect?

Comment: The only problem with containsString is: it's slow for large dataset. Maybe that's why  it returns empty result (cause it exceed the delay limit?)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for clarifying. It's still strange considering that the object (whether string or not) is still the same type.